# NGINX with 2 conditions which need a rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx, host

I have 2 different sites
www.example1.com
www.example2.com

each of them have a folder e.g. 
https://www.example1.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020
https://www.example2.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020

The idea is to apply an nginx rule which matches 2 conditions, the host and uri if there is no .html at the end

This is what i have for appending .html if there is no .html currently present

```
  location ~ ^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }
  location @rewrite {
  rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;
  }
```

I want to apply the above condition only to www.example2.com and NOT www.example1.com

how is this possible? i have tried a few things but location only seems to deal with the URI rather than $host/$uri?

I have tried below:

```
  location ~ ^https://(?![example1])(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$
```

but that does not work.

Also tried this with no luck

```
  set $tmp '';
  if ($http_origin ~ "^https?://(?!(oasis-)).*") {
   set $tmp 1;
  }
  if ($request_uri ~ ^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$) {
   set $tmp "${tmp}1";
  }
  if ($tmp = 11) {
   rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;
  }
```

Comment: Careful with if. I recommend reading [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it can help, but try if you can make it work with [nginx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)